# how to split a pyspark script into multiple files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large Pyspark program which does below steps:

1. General import and Spark object initialization
2. Reading data for category1 from a directory. Files are in compressed format. I am using sc.TextFile() to read all the files in the directory in one go.
3. define schema = StructType([..])
4. createdataframe by applying schema from step 3 on the data from step 2
5. Repeat steps 2, 3, 4 for 3 more categories
6. There are 300, 140, 15 and 10 columns in each category respectively
7. Join data from all the categories on two common columns in all the categories. Two sets are joined using inner and other two using left_outer
8. Store the result in parquet
9. Create a hive table on top of the parquet

I am using Spark 2.0.0/Python 3.4 and I am able to complete all the steps successfully.

I, however, realize that my script is a lengthy 1200 lines of code and it does not look very neat to put everything in the same script.

I plan to:

1. Keep the schema definition in separate files
2. common modules such as, reading data from dir in separate files and just pass the category and dir to read.
3. Idea is to keep the main script clean and manageable.

I have not come across anything that suggests how to maintain large spark code, and general python guidelines may not be entirely applicable, hence the question.

I am looking for any recommendations, guidelines, to-do, not-to-do etc and if possible some sample code.

Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Define a single parameterized helper function

```
read_data(sc, schema_file, data_dir):
  "return df"
  schema = read(schema_file)
  rdd = sc.textFile()
  sqlc = SQLContext(sc)
  df = sqlc.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=schema)
  return df
```

Main program would then be

```
df1 = read_data(sc, sf1, dd1)
df2 = read_data(sc, sf2, dd2)
df3 = read_data(sc, sf3, dd3)
df4 = read_data(sc, sf4, dd4)

# assumes inner joins each with different join attrs
net = (df1.join(df2, (df1["key1a"]==df2["key2a"] 
                      & df1["key1b"]==df2["key2b"]))
          .join(df3, (df1["key1c"]==df3["key3c"]
                      & df1["key1d"]==df3["key3d"]))
          .join(df4, (df1["key1e"]==df4["key4e"]
                      & df1["key1f"]==df4["key4f"])))

# you may wish to remove some duplicated columns, esp. since you said there are many input columns
filt = net.select(...) # or
filt = net.drop(...)

filt.write.parquet("out")
```

Personally I would put the Hive table creation elsewhere, not bundle it into the script.

You have to be careful about using sc (or spark) as a global, especially if the script might be called both interactively and from other code.  I generally add boilerplate to conditionally create sc in the `__main__` context at the bottom of the script a la

```
try:
    # noinspection PyUnboundLocalVariable                                                                                                                                    
    assert sc
except (AssertionError, UnboundLocalError):
    spark_name = ("my app name")
    conf = SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName(spark_name)
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
```